# I want to keep a spatial database of my small firm so i can visualize it in Google earth

Tags: postgresql, postgis, google-earth

I want to manage our spatial data in a database, and I learned Postgres and postGIS are good. I want to be able manage and also visualize the data in Google earth. I don't know where to start from. Is there any help ?

Comment: Define `our spatial data`.  If it is primarily point data you may not need a GIS program. We store a lot of lat/long data and convert it to KML for viewing. We do use polygons to define areas but those are fairly static.

Answer (score 0):

Yes PostGIS extension is used on Postgres to store and manage spatial data. You can use Postgres to store your spatial data. In order to use, postgres table in google earth you need to convert the table columns into kml/kmz.

For that you could use GDAL OGR command line tool. Which convert table into KML with command somthingh like below

```
ogr2ogr -f "kml" file_name.kml PG:"host=myhost user=myloginname \ 
             dbname=mydbname password=mypassword" "myschema.table_name" \
             -s_srs EPSG:<myEPSGcode> -t_srs EPSG:4326
```

EPSG is the coordinate reference system and other parameters are postgres credentials.
You need to explore it a little bit.